# Rewrite URL to remove folder ONLY if URL contains folder name?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am having an issue where my code is rewriting all urls. How can I make it specific so .htaccess will **only** remove the folder name if it is present in the URL. If not, the rule will not execute?

My URL is: `example.com/pages/home.php`
New URL: `example.com/home.php`
If I do `example.com/index.php` I want the rule to ignore it. Or if I do `example.com/admin/login.php`
Here is my sample:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+pages/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule (?!^pages/)^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: So, `/pages/home.php` is the filesystem path that the URL `/home.php` should map to? And `/index.php` and `/admin/index.php` that should be ignored do exist as physical files?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to exclude index.php file from directory removal from URL in .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944284/how-to-exclude-index-php-file-from-directory-removal-from-url-in-htaccess-file)